# Полька - чешский танец

Tags: этимология

Может быть, это не совсем русский язык, но было бы интересно знать.
Насколько я знаю, полька - несмотря на название, танец чешский. Но почему же все-таки он - полька? Имеет это какую-то связь с названием страны Польши или слово просто созвучное?
Наверное, вопрос довольно банальный, но все равно буду благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

См. http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%29 :

[image]